# ON which event of form this function should be called?

Tags: php, ajax

I am newbie with AJAX. I got a script to fetch a data from database using drop down menu And onclick event function was called. I want to do it onload event of form. but is that possible it fetches recently added record, without refreshing page. I mean I am also inserting data at same time. And showing its live preview. Let me know how  to do it. Is onload event of from is ok. or any even where I need to call function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show it constantly then you would have to use setInterval(funcnamem,1000); to poll the function every 1 second so that you can get the updated data. Onload will execute the function during the page load.

*Update*
You can add it in your script section whereever that is either below or above your main html

```
<body>

</body>
</html>
<script>

function yourajaxfunction() {

}

setInterval(yourajaxfunction,1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Where should I use this function, in the form? Please provide some hint code. I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

put it to setInterval()

```
var how_often = 60000; // 6 sec
setInterval(function(){
    //your ajax stuff
}, how_often);
```

Comment: I asked where should I call this function. Means where should be function() written? In the form?